# Sharing a simpler solution to a problem from putnam and beyond

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

To give context this is Problem 1.1.8 from Putnam and Beyond

I have a simple solution for this problem that I would like to share. I checked the book's solution, and although it is very clever, it is also very convoluted (involving the density of rationals on the real line at some point). I would appreciate any feedback and I also would love see your solution to this problem.

Show that there does not exist a strictly increasing function $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ satisfying
$f(2) = 3$ and $f (mn) = f(m)f(n)$ for all $m, n ∈ N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution to this problem:

Let $f$ be such a function, then $f(9) = f(3)^2>f(8)=27$ and so $f(3)>5$. And if $f(3) \ge 7$ then $f(10) > f(9) \ge 49$ which in turn implies that $f(5) \ge \dfrac{f(10)}{f(2)} \ge 17$. Now we can show that $f(15) =f(3)f(5)\ge 7\cdot 17 \ge 119 > f(16)= 81$, and so $f(3) \lt 7$.  Therefore, $f(3)=6$.

Here comes the difficult part of the problem. First notice that $f(7) = \dfrac{f(28)}{f(4)} > \dfrac{f(27)}{f(4)} =24$ and so $f(7) \ge 25$  and $f(5)>\dfrac{f(9)}{f(2)}=12$ and so $f(5) \ge 13$. From this we can conclude that, $f(35) =f(7)f(5)\ge 25\cdot 13 \ge 325 > f(36)=324$. Contradiction!

Although this is very elementary proof, it took me $1.5$ hours of scratch-work.

Comment: I guess I'm dumb, because it took me nearly a minute to figure out $f(3)^2 > f(8).$ I first thought this was a typo (typos are a common error when checking someone else's work), and I was led down some wrong paths. If you had simply begun with $f(9) = f(3)^2 > f(8),$ things would have been much easier to check. Again, maybe I'm just slow at this type of problem, but my suggestion is that busy people are more likely to check over this if you write this up in a very explicit and easy-to-follow/verify style. Nonetheless, (+1) for what seems like a good use of Stack Exchange.

Comment: You're right! Thank you for the suggestion!